# How to get the short link to tweet by php?

Tags: php, twitter

See this code :

```
$tweet->retweeted_status->entities->media[0]->media_url;
```

For example with this i can Get the link of photo of tweets but how can i Get The link of tweet?
The link such as `https:// t.co /lNvfyo04As` 
I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a link *within* a tweet? If so, the first link should be available as:

```
$tweet->retweeted_status->entities->urls[0]->url
```

Comment: and do you know how to get the link of video?!

Comment: and `$tweet->retweeted_status->entities->urls[0]->url` didn't work.

Comment: I want to get the short link such as `https :// t.co/ aSDlkf45` which redirects to the tweet